# ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromRequest return http scheme instead of https

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a web application composed by frontend code that invokes the same api implemented by two backend modules. This api returns a url in a JSON object. The backend modules are both written with spring mvc but in different versions.
The url-building is the same and it is something like this:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/app1/menu", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
   public JsonObject getMenu(HttpServletRequest req) throws IOException {
       JsonObject menu = new JsonObject();
       menu.addProperty("href", ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromRequest(req)
               .replacePath(req.getContextPath())
               .path("/index.html")
               .toUriString());
       return menu;
}
```

As you can see this code simply adds a constant to the incoming request and returns it.
The first app uses spring mvc 4 (4.3.5.RELEASE precisely).
The second module uses the 5.1.4.RELEASE version.
When all these apps are deployed on a load balanced server (2 tomcat instance with a load balancer upfront) and https the problem shows up.
Say that the request url is, for app1, something like this:

```
https://example.com/context/app1/menu
```

The app1 returns correctly

```
https://example.com/context/index.html
```

For the app2 the request issued by the frontend is
    https://example.com/context/app2/menu

And the answer is
    http://example.com/context/another_index.html

So it looses the https scheme

It seems that the ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromRequest has changed behaviour?
I have taken a (quick I admit) look at the commits in the git repo but haven't 
found anything ....